# RxJS how to fire two http requests in parallel but wait for first to complete before second value is emitted

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a UI where I display details about a Game.
The view has two tabs, one with the details and one with the screenshots.

[image]

To construct the Model for the View, I need to get data from 2 different endpoints:

- `/games/:id`
- `/games/:id/screenshots`

The behaviour I am trying to achieve is as follow:

- I want to parallelize the network requests to both API endpoint
- I want the first request (`/games/:id`) always to emit first
- I want the second request (`/games/:id/screenshots`) to emit last, even when it finished before the first one.

I have been able to achieve a working solution, but what I cannot achieve is "parallelize and wait".

This is my current implementation

```
export class GameService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private state: GameState = {
    ...initialState,
  };
  private store = new BehaviorSubject<GameState>(this.state);
  private store$ = this.store.asObservable();

findGame(id: string) {
    const game$ = this.http.get<Game>(`${env.BASE_URL}/games/${id}`).pipe(
      delay(1500),
      tap((game) => {
        this.state = { ...this.state, selectedGame: game };
        this.store.next({ ...this.state });
      })
    );

    const screenshots$ = this.http
      .get<APIResponse<{ image: string }>>(
        `${env.BASE_URL}/games/${id}/screenshots`
      )
      .pipe(
        delay(2500),
        map(({ results: screenshots }) => screenshots),
        tap((screenshots) => {
          if (this.state.selectedGame) {
            this.state.selectedGame.screenshots = [...screenshots];
            this.store.next({ ...this.state });
          }
        })
      );

     return game$.pipe(concatMap(() => screenshots$));
  }
}
```

This line

```
return game$.pipe(concatMap(() => screenshots$));
```

allows me to wait for the first request to finish before the second one can emit, but it also means that the network request is not initiated until the first observable emits.

I have tried to use `merge` but it becomes very complex to determine the shape of the emitted value and the code becomes quite "dirty"

**How can I parallelize both requests, but wait for the first to finish before the second one emits?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delayWhen`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, delayWhen, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function getGame() {
  console.log('game requested');
  return of('foo').pipe(
     delay(2500),
     tap(() => console.log('game returned')),
  );
}

function getScreenshots() {
  console.log('screenshots requested');
  return of('bar').pipe(
     delay(1000),
     tap(() => console.log('screenshots returned')),
  );
}


const game$ = getGame().pipe(shareReplay(1));
const screenshots$ = getScreenshots().pipe(
  delayWhen(() => game$),
);

game$.subscribe(() => console.log('game received'));
screenshots$.subscribe(() => console.log('screenshots received'));
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6jmk4j?file=index.ts

Comment: why do we need `shareReplay` on the first stream?

Comment: Yes otherwise game request wil be fired twice here

Comment: I understand, and based on this logic if I want to turn both of them as hot at the same time, should I use `merge(game$, screenshots$)`?

Comment: `merge` is possible, but `forkJoin` for example too. That is totally on you and depends on how your subscription data should look like. `forkJoin` will give both responses in array, while `merge` will give you the responses sequentially.

Comment: worked like a charm! Thank you for your help!

For my own learning, the `shareReplay` is necessary because the `delayWhen` will subscribe to the source (`games$`) obs only once it has emitted, and therefore this allows us to immediately pull the latest value, as opposed to starting a new stream?

Comment: Yes, the value will be shared to both subscribers